# AWX - Can't accept github fingerprint

Tags: github, kubernetes, ssh, ansible-awx

I freshly installed awx 19.5.1, on minikube, and i justed wanted to try to add a project linked to a private github repository. but i can't synchronize the project using the url git@github.com:myproject.git, because i can't accept the fingerprint, and the https url refused the cred.

```
TASK [update project using git] ************************************************
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.121.4)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:p2QAMXNIC1TJYWeIOttrVc98/R1BUFWu3/LiyKgUfQM.
```

Any advices ?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the keys from https://api.github.com/meta and insert them into either `~/.ssh/known_hosts` by prefixing them with `github.com` and a space or into `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` if you control that on the system.

Alternately, you can write them into any file with suitable permissions, and use `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -oUserKnownHostsFile=path/to/my/file"`.

Comment: Thanks ! I wasn't abble to access the container in cli, it works for me now! i need to upskill on kubernetes now ^^